# Ubuntu server 16.04 VNC only showing terminal and a file explorer window

Tags: server, vnc

I recently installed Ubuntu server 16.04 and tried to get vnc running with gnome-core running as the user environment. Initially after installation I only got the classic gray screen when logging into vnc and after a lot of googling I managed to get the vnc window to display a terminal window and a file explorer window. I have tried everything I could to get the screen to show the full desktop but I have now given up and realized i need to ask for help. Below is the contents of my xstartup, the log and a screen shot of vnc.

xstartup

```
#!/bin/sh
def
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

metacity &
gnome-settings-daemon &
gnome-panel &
nautilus &
gnome-terminal &
gnome-session --session=gnome-core &
```

Log

```
08/05/16 15:13:03 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.10
08/05/16 15:13:03 Copyright (C) 2000-2009 TightVNC Group
08/05/16 15:13:03 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
08/05/16 15:13:03 All Rights Reserved.
08/05/16 15:13:03 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
08/05/16 15:13:03 Desktop name 'X' (NAS:1)
08/05/16 15:13:03 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
08/05/16 15:13:03 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/' not found - ignoring
/home/charley/.vnc/xstartup: 2: /home/charley/.vnc/xstartup: def: not found
/home/charley/.vnc/xstartup: 9: /home/charley/.vnc/xstartup: gnome-panel: not found

(gnome-settings-daemon:3080): rfkill-plugin-WARNING **: Could not open RFKILL control device, please verify your installation

(gnome-settings-daemon:3080): media-keys-plugin-WARNING **: Unable to inhibit keypresses: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Permission denied

** (gnome-settings-daemon:3080): WARNING **: Unable to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

** (process:3169): WARNING **: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

(gnome-settings-daemon:3080): color-plugin-WARNING **: failed to obtain org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-profile auth

(gnome-settings-daemon:3080): PackageKit-WARNING **: failed to set proxy: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/service.py", line 654, in _message_cb
    (candidate_method, parent_method) = _method_lookup(self, method_name, interface_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/service.py", line 246, in _method_lookup
    raise UnknownMethodException('%s is not a valid method of interface %s' % (method_name, dbus_interface))
dbus.exceptions.UnknownMethodException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Unknown method: SetProxy is not a valid method of interface org.freedesktop.PackageKit


(gnome-settings-daemon:3080): updates-plugin-WARNING **: failed to set proxies: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/service.py", line 654, in _message_cb
    (candidate_method, parent_method) = _method_lookup(self, method_name, interface_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/service.py", line 246, in _method_lookup
    raise UnknownMethodException('%s is not a valid method of interface %s' % (method_name, dbus_interface))
dbus.exceptions.UnknownMethodException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Unknown method: SetProxy is not a valid method of interface org.freedesktop.PackageKit

Window manager warning: Failed to load theme "Ambiance": Failed to find a valid file for theme Ambiance

Type  :quit<Enter>  to exit Vim                                        1,1           Top
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kGlY.jpg)

Comment: I have the same problem :-(